# How do I receive emails in e-commerce website on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have made some code to send email and receive email for my website however, it keeps giving me an error message. The error message can be accessed through the link below, or a short version has been copied and pasted here. How do I successfully allow the customer to send me an email? In this example I want to use tanz61791@gmail.com as the customer to send an email to aleksanderhowell@gmail.com as the customer support email.

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.marketing4growth.com :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
> https://flareapp.io/share/v5pwB27E#F59

Some code I have used to create this functionality of allowing the customer to fill in a form to send an email to me for customer support help is shown below. If you want to see the full code, you can through my GitHub repository link located below the code shown.

SendEmailController.php

```
public function send(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required'
    ]);
    $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'message' => $request->message
    );
    Mail::to('aleksanderhowell@gmail.com')->send(new SendMail($data));
    return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
}
```

SendMail.php

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('tanz61791@gmail.com')->subject('New Customer Enquiry')- 
>view('dynamic_email')->with('data', $this->data);
}
```

.env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=80
MAIL_USERNAME=aleksanderhowell
MAIL_PASSWORD=^[qqP-mJV8HG#FPN
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

https://github.com/xiaoheixi/blog

Comment: hope password is not real? change your pass immediately :)

Comment: Where is `smtp.marketing4growth.com` coming from? It's not anywhere in the code you've shared. Are you sure you're using the .env file?

Comment: Are you by any chance a friend of [this question's OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63965141/2821954)? Both of you are asking a similar question regarding SMTP for the site `marketing4growth.com.au`.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody answered, here is PHP solution but not Laravel specific -

PHP has extension called imap.so, it can connect and manage IMAP and POP3 mailboxes.

You can use it to read the contents of the mailbox.

Another solution is to pipe the email to your application. Supposing you host on Linux - On sendmail this is difficult, but we did it about 20 years ago. On postfix is very easy - one line in the conf.

However both solutions are not perfect.

Most PHP servers come without imap.so

Tinkering with the webserver require root access and I dont know any shared hosting who will do it for you.

About Laravel specific solution search for Laravel POP3 and definitely you will found lots of modules you can use.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question about OP wanting to access their email in the Laravel app. It looks like it's about creating a web form that users can use to send email to OPs support email

Comment: May be I did not get the question.  Let author comment I will delete then